# Symmetrical body workouts to compensate for imbalance

Tags: upper-body-workout

The problem with my body is that I'm so right handed so that my left upper body almost look wasted. My MAC (Mid Arm Circumference) on my left side is 30 while my MAC on my right side is 36. It's the same with my pectoralis muscles, lattismus dorsi, etc. How can I correct this? Are there any particular workouts that I should concentrate on?

Comment: Are you doing any exercises at the moment? Is it possible that you already doing them imbalanced?

Comment: How much does their strength differ?

Comment: If you are doing unilateral exercises of any kind, *always* start with the weaker side first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a body symmetry issue you need to address a few things. For one, work out! if you just do you daily tasks you're going to favor one side, that means one side is going to be disproportionate.

Next you need to counter the imbalance, you can do this by increasing the amount of single side workouts(one arm, one leg, one pec, ect). Work the weak side harder than the strong side every other work out, you'll start to see the difference. Just like any problem you're going to have to address the specific area if you want to solve it.

When in doubt up the amount of weight for both sides, force the weak side to up it's game. Use dumbbells they will make your body keep you honest, they reduce bad habits and don't allow for you to cheat and use one side more than the other.

Answer (score 3):

If you do free-weight exercises with good form and appropriate weights, this problem should gradually correct itself.  The only important caveat would be that if you do exercises with dumbbells, you need to make sure that you do the same weight and same number of repetitions with you strong right hand as you do with your weaker left hand.  For anything you do, you'll have to use a weight that your (weaker) left side can handle.  That weight might not be enough to stimulate your stronger right side, but that's what you want, because it would force your left side to grow stronger, while your right side will stay about the same.  Eventually, your left side will start to catch up.

With exercise machines there's a chance that one arm could compensate for the other, so you might want to stay away from those.